# Crear tabla html desde json con javascript

Tags: javascript, json, bucle-for, html-tabla

Estoy tratando de crear una tabla a partir de un json que tengo con datos, creo que se visualice en mi html pero no logro que aparezca correctamente. Quiero guardarlo en una cookie para que se visualice.

Antes de realizar el for, pasaba el json en una variable en la que hacia json.stringify pero me sacaba una frase con todo junto, he decidido hacer un for para ver si podía realizar cada apartado en una celda pero ya no me saca ningun resultado.

```
     let fruteria = {
            frutas: [
              {
                nombre: "manzana",
                Precio: 3.5,
              },
              {
                nombre: "cereza",
                Precio: 2,
              },
            ],
          };
    //cambio el valor por el que yo deseo
    fruteria.frutas[0].nombre = platano;

var tabla = resultado; //variable asignada getElementById de mi tabla (no añadida aqui)
            for (var i = 0; i < fruteria.length; i++){
          var row = "<tr><td>"+fruteria.frutas[i].nombre+"</td><td>"+fruteria.frutas[i].precio+"</td></tr>";
          console.log(row);
          tabla.innerHTML += row;
          Cookies.set("frutas", row,{expire:30});
          Cookies.get("frutas");
        }
```

**Estoy usando mozilla firefox y para las cookies estoy usando una API**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo principal es que el for lo estas haciendo sobre el tamaño del objeto fruteria, pero el arreglo que contiene la información esta dentro de fruteria. Por eso al iterar no retorna nada. Es decir el for debería iterar mientras i < fruteria.frutas.length

Ademas, estas asignando platano como una variable (aunque no se si la definías anteriormente). Y también, dentro del for accedes a la propiedad fruteria.frutas[i].precio pero en el objeto se define como Precio (la mayúscula es importante)

Te dejo las correcciones que probé y funcionó (obviando la parte de las cookies)

```
let fruteria = {
    frutas: [{
            nombre: "manzana",
            precio: 3.5,
        },
        {
            nombre: "cereza",
            precio: 2,
        },
    ],
};
//cambio el valor por el que yo deseo
fruteria.frutas[0].nombre = "platano";

var tabla = document.getElementById("tabla"); //variable asignada getElementById de mi tabla (no añadida aqui)
for (var i = 0; i < fruteria.frutas.length; i++) {
    var row = "<tr><td>" + fruteria.frutas[i].nombre + "</td><td>" + fruteria.frutas[i].precio + "</td></tr>";
    console.log(row);
    tabla.innerHTML += row;
    Cookies.set("frutas", row, {
        expire: 30
    });
    Cookies.get("frutas");
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!!! llevaba dias intentandolo!!!!!!